# Customize Redirect After Form Login in symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, path

I want to redirect to this url after login :

```
http://localhost/ekarhabty/web/app_dev.php/Plateforme/E-commerce/commande/coordonnees
```

This is my Security.yml :

```
 form_login:
          login_path: fos_user_security_login
          check_path: fos_user_security_check
          always_use_default_target_path: false
          default_target_path:   Accueilpage
          target_path_parameter: go_to
          failure_path_parameter: back_to
```

This my twig file : login.html.twig :

```
   <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
      {% if csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
      {% endif %}
     <label for="username"> Email ou Identifiant <span class="required">*</span></label>
     <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required"  class="form-control"/>

      <label for="password">Mot de passe <span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" class="form-control"/>
       {% if error %}
       <div> 
       <b style="color:red">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</b>
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        <p class="forgot-pass"><a href="{{path('fos_user_resetting_check_email') }}">Mot de passe oublié ?</a></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="go_to" value="{{ path('coordonnees_commande') }}" />
         <input type="hidden" name="back_to" value="{{ path('login_commande') }}" />
         <button type="submit" class="button" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="" /><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>&nbsp; <span>Se connecter</span</button>
    </form>
```

but this produces URLs like  :

/ekarhabty/web/app_dev.php/Plateforme/E-commerce/commande/coordonnees

And I get this error after submit : 
    No route found for "GET /ekarhabty/web/app_dev.php/Plateforme/E-
    commerce/commande/coordonnees" (from 
    "http://localhost/ekarhabty/web/app_dev.php/Plateforme/E-
    commerce/commande/login"

Edited : 
This my routing.yml file

```
login_commande:
    path:     /commande/login
    defaults: { _controller: EKEcommerceBundle:Commande:loginCommande }

coordonnees_commande:
    path:     /commande/coordonnees
    defaults: { _controller: EKEcommerceBundle:Commande:coordonnees }
```

Comment: Could you show how routes are defined for route "coordonnees_commande"?

Comment: I edited my answer , can you check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Symfony and routing is working correctly.

You are redirected to wrong place, because you have Symfony running from a subfolder ***/ekarhabty/web***. There are few solutions here:

1. *(reccomended)* Deploy Symfony in a way, that "web" folder is a document root of the server, so URLs for symfony looks like "http://{your.domain}/app_dev.php" without any folder before "app_dev.php".
2. Use "url()" instead of "path()" to generate route. But then only current case is resolved, you might have many similar problems in future.

Comment: Thank you very much , you save my week :D ;) .I replace path by url and it worked :D .